# Using lambda as an adapter?

Tags: c#, lambda

I am not sure what it means to use lamba expressions as method adapters. I guess it has something to do parameters that in some cases do not have to be entered but not sure about it. I would be very thankful for an example and a bit of explanation.
Thnanks

Comment: It's very hard to answer this without any context. Where did you read about using lambda expressions as "method adapters" and what was the wider context?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: mentioned in the book from John Sharp - "Using lamba expressions as Adapter". I cannot recall exactly but I am quite sure it was about adapting methods with parameters to parameter-less ones (well, just a way how enable running them like this).

Comment: I suggest you delete this question and ask another one with more information when you have the book in front of you. You can't really expect anyone to answer a question where you can't even remember the relevant context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example if you have a function `foo` that takes an `Func<int, string>`, but you don't care about the latter `string` for your existing method `handler`, then you can do:

```
foo( (theint, thestring) => { handler(theint) });
```

This is the adapter "ducktape" use of lamba.